Order of Conditions in `if ... else if ... else ...` in C++
I'm trying to figure out how to write the most optimal if ... else if ... else ... statement in C++.
Suppose that we have 3 possible conditions based on some n variable value: n = 0, 0 < n < 100, and n = 100. Let's assume that n = 0 will occur in 1% cases, 0 < n < 100 – 90%, and n = 100 – 9%. Note that if ... else if ... else ... will be executed many times and the value of n will be different each time.
My first assumption was to put conditions in the descending order (the most frequent – first, the least frequent – last) like below. However, the first condition will have 3 boolean expressions. And since the first condition will be always executed (in 100% cases) and it consists of 3 boolean expressions (>, <, and &&), those 3 expressions will be executed in 100% cases. (Maybe there will be some optimization made by a compiler, and it will somehow be reduced to 2 expressions.) The second condition will be executed in 10% cases and the third condition – in 1% cases.
So, given that there will be a 1 000 iterations, there will be 3 100 boolean expressions evaluated (3 000 + 100).
if ((n > 0) && (n < 100)) {  // 3 boolean expressions will be executed in 100% cases.
  ...
} else if (n == 100) {  // 1 additional boolean expression – in 10% cases.
  ...
} else {  // n = 0  // No additional boolean expressions – in 1% cases.
  ...
}

If to change the order of conditions (so that to eliminate the condition with 3 boolean expressions), there will be 1 910 boolean expressions evaluated (1 000 + 910).
if (n == 100) {  // 1 boolean expression will be executed in 100% cases.
  ...
} else if (n == 0) {  // 1 additional boolean expression – in 91% cases.
  ...
} else {  // 0 < n < 100  // No additional boolean expressions – in 90% cases.
  ...
}

Do I understand it right? If no, how to properly optimize the code with if ... else if ... else ... for speed?
Update: Based on the comments, did a test. The first variant gives less lines of the compiled code than the second one. Don't know Assembly language, so I'm not sure whether less lines is better in this case.

Please share the performance benchmarks showing the difference between the various orderings.

First of all, when doing benchmarks remember to always build with optimizations enabled. Secondly, compare the generated code with each other, which is easy to do on e.g. the compiler explorer.

Usually last else clause executes faster because don't need extra jump instruction. So if (n == 100) ... else if (n == 0) ... else ... ; But of course, need to be benchmarked.

Because of short-circuiting operations (part of the standard, i.e. compiler agnostic), the numbers you give are wrong. Moreover, the number of cycles lost in that is going to be very small compared to whatever is going on inside the { ... }, good luck benchmarking that. For the same reason, it does not look, to me, that whatever you hope to learn with this can be applied as a general rule. A more realistic if (someFunctionWithSideEffect(n) == 0) ... will be dominated by what happens in the function, not by how you order the ifs.

Leave the performance to optimizer. Because premature optimization is the source of evil. I'd rather focus on program readability instead.

IMHO, excessively narrow and deep analysis. All is much simpler. switch (n) { case 0: ...; break; case 100: ...; break; default: ...; break; }

Write the code in the most logical, understandable way. If there's a performance issue once you've written your code and profiling shows that the order of the statements matters, then you can try optimising it

@3CxEZiVIQ I agree that a switch statement might be appropriate here as it gives the compiler the option of using a jump table (which I have never seen generated for nested if statements). In the more general case of nested if statements that need to be seriously fast and are checking a given value then arranging the tests in a tree that splits as near as you can get to 50:50 at each level is usually as good as you can get. Failing that return the most frequent on the shortest path through the (assembler) code. Todays optimising compilers are very good so it is almost never worthwhile.

If you have an if in your code then performance is affected by branch predictions, the more nested your if's the more likely it is branch prediction will fail and that will cost you performance. That said if performance is an issue (most likely it is not in this case) then you should use profilers to find the worst bottlenecks in your code (or design) first and adjust them.

Convert the three conditions to an int with the value of 0, 1 or 2 (one value for each of the 3 conditions), then use switch/case.

You're not accounting for the fact that &&  (and ||) does short-circuiting.   So if ((n > 0) && (n < 100)) {stuff();} else if (n == 0) ... is equivalent to if (n > 0) { if (n < 100) {stuff();} } else if (n == 0) ...  and never tests n < 100 if n > 0 is false.

One of your counts is off. You say:
if ((n > 0) && (n < 100)) {  // 3 boolean expressions will be executed in 100% cases.

But (1) && is not a Boolean expression, but an implicit if because it short-circuits the expression, and (2) due to the short-circuiting the second half n < 100 will be executed only 99% of the cases. Only n > 0 will be examined in 100% of the cases.
Apart from that, you are focusing too much on how frequently conditions are evaluated. This is a secondary concern, because first and foremost do note that it is unavoidable to check two conditionals before the most frequent branch can be entered.
With this in mind, you can now begin to ask if it is possible to avoid checking one of the two conditions with higher probability. The conditions are n > 0 (false in 1% of cases) and n < 100 (false in 10% of cases). Now, if you check n > 0 first, then you can avoid checking the other in 1% of the cases, but when you check n < 100 first, then you can avoid the other check in 10% of the cases. So, that is what you should do:
if (n == 100) {  // get 10% of the cases out of the way
  ...
} else if (n == 0) {  // unavoidable second check after first check failed
  ...
} else {  // most frequent case needs both checks
  ...
}

(This assumes that [0 ... 100] are the only values that n can take.)

Thank you for additional explanations! Your answer does make sense.

However, most CPUs have an essentially free test for zero or not zero which may tip the balance in favour of having that test first. Only profiling the actual code can tell you which version is fastest (and it is only worth doing this as a last resort). Be aware that modern compilers are smart and if they can implement the if statement as conditional moves (with no branch penalty) then they will do so. Coding to make that easier for the compiler to see is sometimes necessary in code that has to be fast.
